# Vertex shader recieving input but no output is generated

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have this vertex shader, which simply passes the position given and passes the UV and color to the fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core                                                   
layout (location = 0) in vec2 in_pos;                            
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_texUV;                             
layout (location = 2) in vec4 in_color;                             
out vec2 ex_texUV;                                                  
out vec4 ex_color;                                                  
                                                                              
uniform mat4 projection;                                            
                                                                    
void main()                                                         
{                                                                   
    gl_Position = vec4(in_pos, 0.0, 1.0) * projection;           
    ex_texUV    = in_texUV;                                         
    ex_color    = in_color;                                         
}
```

Edit: The fragment shader is shown here, and all uniforms are properly set:

```c
#version 330 core                                               
in vec2 in_texUV;                                               
in vec4 in_color;                                               
out vec4 out_color;                                             
                                                                
uniform vec2 screenSize;                                        
uniform vec3 transparentColour;                                 
uniform sampler2D sprite;                                       
                                                                
uniform sampler2D palette;                                      
uniform int paletteLines[0x100];                                
                                                                
void main()                                                     
{                                                               
    if (in_color.a == 0.0) {                                    
        vec4 coord = gl_FragCoord - 0.5;                        
        vec2 screenPos;                                         
        screenPos.x = coord.x * screenSize.x;                   
        screenPos.y = coord.y * screenSize.y;                   
                                                                
        int id = paletteLines[int(screenPos.y)];                
                                                                
        int index = int(texture2D(sprite, in_texUV).r * 255);   
                                                                
        if (index == 0)                                         
            discard;                                            
                                                                
        vec2 palvec;                                            
        palvec.x = index;                                       
        palvec.y = id;                                          
                                                                
        out_color = texture(palette, palvec);                   
    }                                                           
}
```

(The projection variable is properly set, [shown using NVIDIA Nsight.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnCdz.png))

Both the vertex and fragment shader have been edited to be simple passthroughs (even setting the fragment shader to a constant `vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`,) but it's always shown nothing.

To setup for the shader, I first set up the VAO and VBO to pass from a list of `DrawVertex`:

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glGenBuffers(2, &GFXVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GFXVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DrawVertex), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DrawVertex), (void *)(sizeof(short) * 2));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DrawVertex), (void *)(sizeof(short) * 4));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

and then draw using the code below (the VAO and VBO are ensured to be bound, and `gfxShader` is just a helper to use a program):

```cpp
gfxShader.use();

// [setup the program, change uniforms as necessary]

// lastRenderCount is how many to render
// gfxPolyList is the list of DrawVertex
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, lastRenderCount * sizeof(DrawVertex), gfxPolyList, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, lastRenderCount);

gfxShader.stop();
```

However, despite this, although [RenderDoc shows that the input is being passed through,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ffRI.png) the [output shows nothing at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyk19.png) On top of this, NVIDIA Nsight says that [no fragments are being drawn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEHUs.png) Where could I be going wrong?

For context, here is struct `DrawVertex`:

```cpp
struct DrawVertex {
    short x;
    short y;
    short u;
    short v;

    Color color = 0; //0xRRGGBBAA
};
```

Comment: "*The projection variable is properly set, shown using NVIDIA Nsight*" I don't see that from what you've shown. Specifically, I don't see the actual matrix data itself, which would prove that you've provided valid data. This is especially important as your matrix multiplication is backwards.

Comment: [Here it is shown in the VS tab of the `glDrawArrays` call.](https://i.imgur.com/D1BYYUx.png) Even when I comment the projection multiplication to directly passthrough the data though, nothing shows up. I will take the backwards multiplication into account, though, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a defined and bound fragment shader ? If so, can you show its code ? If not, then you need to make one, setup its inputs to match the outputs of your vertex shader, and create a single vec4 output inside the fragment shader that will be your final fragment color. Fragment shaders are technically optional, but for actual color output, they need to be present and bound or else the fragment color output is undefined, you can find more about this [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader).

Comment: I've edited it to add the fragment shader now.

Answer (score 0):

```
gl_Position = vec4(in_pos, 0.0, 1.0) * projection;
```

This is wrong. Matrix multiplication is not commutative. Should be:

```
gl_Position = projection * vec4(in_pos, 0.0, 1.0);
```

If you don't believe me, try this:

```
glm::mat4 proj = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 3.0f, 6.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f
};
glm::vec4 vec = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
glm::vec4 result1 = proj * vec;
glm::vec4 result2 = vec * proj;
std::cout << "result1: " << result1.x << result1.y << result1.z << result1.w << '\n';
std::cout << "result2: " << result2.x << result2.y << result2.z << result2.w << '\n';

// Output:
result1: 0167
result2: 5701
```

https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

**Edit:** Your fragment shader runs only if `in_color.a == 0.0`? Are you sure this is correct? Maybe you meant to use `!=` instead.

Comment: As mentioned in a prior comment, I've now since fixed the backwards multiplication, even though, as I mentioned in an edit to the post, if I make it a direct pass through, nothing shows up all the same. And yes, I'm sure this is correct, as a vertex of this shader can either take texture UVs mapped to a palette using `GL_RED` with a sprite texture, or use colors. I set alpha to 0 for the color when it isn't in use. (And, again, if I set it to a constant `vec4` with full alpha, nothing still shows up.)